# Hiding all columns in Tableau graph whose value is below a threshold

Tags: tableau-api

I am using a Tableau worksheet having 10 factories (entries) and 10 measure values for each factory/entry. There are a total of 100 columns in my Tableau worksheet.

I want to hide all columns whose value is zero and only show non zero values. But since each column is a different measure value, I can't filter or sort them. How do I go about this?

Comment: why should you have a separate column for same type of variable.  Ideally you should have 11 columns at max.  try pivoting (melting) your data longer

Answer (score 0):

If you have tableau prep, then melt your data in pivoting.  In prep you can easily remove nil or zero values easily.
Ideally you should have 11 columns, 1 for factory_id and other 10 for measures.

Alternatively, break all 10 factories in 10 groups of data and Union them after adding an id field for each group.

This link will help https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2018/4/how-perform-coordinated-pivots-tableau-prep-86661